# Script for using metatype to convert metafont to TTF?

Tags: fonts, metafont, truetype

In the [metatype FAQ](http://metatype.sourceforge.net/faq.php), there's a section called "I have Metafont sources of some font. How could I convert it to TrueType using Metatype?" In that, he lays out a dozen steps that really should be scripted. Does anyone know of such a script? (I understand the result won't look very good at low font sizes.)

Comment: Perhaps you could adapt mf2pt1 (which is a perl script)?

Comment: Is Opentype an acceptable target?  I ask because there are good quality converters from Type-1 fonts to OTF.

Comment: If I can use it in OpenOffice, then it's acceptable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.

Comment: See also [How to convert the OTF font to win Type1 font (Pfb) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332755/how-to-convert-the-otf-font-to-win-type1-font-pfb) ■ There are some tools over at [How Can I Convert Postscript Type 1 font to .otf or .ttf? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322635/how-can-i-convert-postscript-type-1-font-to-otf-or-ttf) for converting type1 to otf/ttf although I haven't tried...

Comment: The mf2pt1 tool is a popular utility for converting Metafont sources to PostScript Type 1 fonts, which can then be converted to TrueType using other tools such as FontForge or Adobe Font Development Kit for OpenType (AFDKO).

There is a Python script called mf2tt.py that can automate the process of converting Metafont sources to TrueType using Metatype. This script can be found on GitHub at https://github.com/eti/mf2tt.