# How to convert the OTF font to win Type1 font (Pfb)

Tags: fonts, type1, otftotfm

I have lot of OTF fonts I am using normal LaTeX (I am not familiar with xelatex), I want to install the font in MiKTeX, How to convert the OTF font to win Type1 font (Pfb) for font conversion in LaTeX, any free softwares are available?

Comment: it is likely to be _much_ simpler to use xelatex or lualatex. Apart from converting the font format you would then have to re-encode the font in to (potentially hundreds) of 256-character fonts as classic latex can only handle 256 characters in each font, then you have to arrange your font macros to know which font each character is in. (This is possible, and done for example in the cjk packages but using lua or xe tex and a single opentype font is _much_ easier)

Comment: You can use the LCDF-tools (https://www.lcdf.org/type/) and autoinst from the fontools (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/) but as David already wrote, installing type1 fonts for pdflatex needs some knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resources of free fonts for pdftex

The easiest way to get your fonts useable for pdftex would be to download them. The main resource is here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ .

You mention, that you have lots of OTF fonts. Maybe you can get the type 1 fonts from the same source and the »helper files« from CTAN. The fonts »Rotis« e.g. isn't free, but you could get everything except the fonts itself here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/ -- there are many others.

Improbable, but not impossible: get the fonts with [getnonfreefonts](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/)

### Do it yourself

I'm a user, without much (if any) skills when it comes to writing code. [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) already mentioned the LCDF-tools and autoinst.

I haven't tested for years, it used to be a pain to get a working installation. I once used fontsforge to convert OTF to pfb, but then some glyphs were wrong...

My advice: have fun, but limit time and effort.

### Let somebody else do it

If it is important to you to get a certain fonts working with pdftex, let somebody else do it for some money. I will postpone using LuaTeX as long as possible, because it is slower than pdftex.

Some time ago Ulrike performed such a job for me (see here: http://www.troubleshooting-tex.de/ ) and I can really recommend her work!