# Does the specific Bodoni font, "Bodoni Book Pro", exist for use in LaTeX anywhere?

Tags: fonts

I'd like to use the specific font: Bodoni Book Pro. I haven't yet seen any LaTeX compatible distrubutions of this font.

I have found the font [here](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/bodoni/pro-book/#index)

I'm certainly willing to pay for the font, but I'm unsure if I could even use this in LaTeX.

Does anyone know:

- Does Bodoni Book Pro exist already for use in LaTeX
- If not can I use the font from the above link if I purchase and download it?
- If not to above, is it possible to convert or generate the LaTeX compatible font from the source specified in the link?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't. You can use as is with `xelatex` and `fontspec`. If you want to use it with pdflatex, you'll have to do all the job making virtual fonts (`.vf` files, `.tfm`, `.fd`). Other than that, there exists a Bodoni-like font ready to use names`libre-bodoni`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the reference to `libre-bodoni` I'll take a look.

Comment: There are many OTF Bodoni fonts that will NOT have the same graphemes even if you ignore ligatures Thus they will not look the same as "Book Pro" that's including Ctan  https://ctan.org/pkg/gfsbodoni and they will not have the same number of styles or Unicode variants for the same character If you need specific you will need to spend longer than its worth shopping around. Your key task is checking the target purchasable font is broad / wide enough coverage for your needs, maths ? look at variations here https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/bodoni/pro-book/glyphs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several Type 1 versions of Bodoni available for LaTeX, including [GFS Bodoni](https://ctan.org/pkg/gfsbodoni?lang=en) and [Libre Bodoni](https://ctan.org/pkg/librebodoni).  There are also a handful of packages providing only LaTeX font metrics for copyrighted obsolete commercial fonts.

Looking at the tech specs in your link, the commercial Bodoni Book Pro is an OpenType font. You can use any OpenType, TrueType, Graphite or AAT font with the `fontspec` package, in either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, including GFS Bodoni, [Libre Bodoni](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/libre-bodoni) and [Bodoni XT](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bodonixt).  Of these, GFS Bodoni supports Greek, comes in bold, italic and bold italic faces, and is probably included in your TeX distribution already.  (You might also find the slab-serif [Bodonitown](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bodonitown) an interesting companion.)

It is possible to [convert OpenType fonts to Type1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332755/how-to-convert-the-otf-font-to-win-type1-font-pfb), and then [install them in LaTeX](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf), but that’s a lot of work for worse results.