# Write style design

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

[image]

how I can write like in the picture above ??

Comment: Not really matching that one, but have a look here: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ . // Why do you tag it with tikz-something?

Comment: Looks a bit like the Lancia Bodoni font / the font Lancia uses: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lancia_Bodoni_Font.jpg // If so, see also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469463/does-the-specific-bodoni-font-bodoni-book-pro-exist-for-use-in-latex-anywher .

Comment: Please accept the answer you already have

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[rgb]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pdfrender}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, patterns.meta}
\newcounter{myn}%
\newcommand{\design}[1]{%
\definecolor{mycyan}{RGB}{80, 200, 230}%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=\themyn, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base]
\node[transparent!100, fill=transparent!0] (n) {#1};
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10];%encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base]
\filldraw[thin, black, pattern color=mycyan, pattern={Lines[angle=44, distance=0.28mm, line width=0.22pt]}] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\filldraw[thin, black, pattern color=mycyan, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=0.30mm, line width=0.24pt]}] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\filldraw[thin, black, pattern color=mycyan, pattern={Lines[angle=46, distance=0.32mm, line width=0.26pt]}] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\fill[black, path fading=\themyn, fit fading=false] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
\node{\textpdfrender{
TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
LineWidth=0.6pt,
StrokeColor=mycyan,
LineJoinStyle=Round,
}{#1}};
\stepcounter{myn}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}\color{white}
~\\
This is not a \design{\Huge\bf MATH} problem.\\
This is not a {\Huge\bf MATH} problem.\\
~\\
\design{\Large\bf This is a huge problem}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text in white and cyan striped]

[image: The word "MATH" in striped cyan]

Answer (score 6):

Since the OP did originally tag it with Tikz, a drawing might be what is wanted rather than a particular font.  I can't help with Tikz, but in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) you have the `glyph` operator that lets you get at the outline path of a character from a font.  This would let you produce something like this:

[image]

although it's a bit harder to make it look hand drawn.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
newinternal thatch_angle;
newinternal thatch_space;
thatch_angle := 52;
thatch_space := 16;
def rule expr p = _apth := p; _thatch enddef;
def _thatch text t =
    d_ := 2 abs (urcorner _apth - llcorner _apth);
    draw begingroup; save T; picture T; T = image(
        for y=-d_ step thatch_space until d_:
            draw (left--right) scaled d_ rotated 1/8 normaldeviate shifted (0, y) t;
        endfor) rotated thatch_angle shifted center _apth;
        clip T to _apth;
        T endgroup
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    numeric x; x = 0;
    background := black;
    drawoptions(withcolor (0, 13/16, 15/16));
    for s = "M", "A", "T", "H":
        picture g;
        g = glyph s of "ptmr8r";
        numeric n; n = 0;
        for i within g:
            if odd incr n: 
                rule pathpart i shifted (x, 0) withpen pencircle scaled 8;
            else:
                unfill pathpart i shifted (x, 0);
            fi
            draw pathpart i shifted (x, 0) withpen pencircle scaled 4;
        endfor
        x := x + xpart (urcorner g - llcorner g);
        if s = "A": % hack the kerning...
            x := x - 132;
        fi
    endfor
    picture P; P = currentpicture; 
    currentpicture := nullpicture;
    drawoptions();
    bboxmargin := 40;
    fill bbox P withcolor background; draw P;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You need to compile this with `lualatex`.

Comment: thnak you very much, and if I want to write with this style the titles in a document of one command can you help me ?

Comment: that's a different question -- you *could* use MP to format all your section titles like that, but it would probably look horrible.  And you would need to take a more general approach to the kerning instead of my simple hack.  I don;t think I'd recommend it.

Comment: yes I totally agree with you but I think for the title of a bookin or the cover and if you can adopt the size to make it small it works with the titles too

Comment: how can i use MP ??

Comment: @abdellahqal , to use this font see the answer from @hpekristiansen . He defines a macro called `\design ` and wraps text with it like you'd do with any other macro in Latex.